# FFMPEG video by using images with transition effects from top to bottom and bottom to top

Tags: ffmpeg, transition, effects

I am successfully able to convert a sequence of images into a video. But now my requirement is to put some transition effects like left to right ,top to bottom or bottom to top to be shown in video with the change of every image. Please provide me suitable ffmpeg command to have transition effects in video.

Comment: Actually i am using this command shell_exec("ffmpeg -r 1/6 -qscale 2 -i img%03d.png output.mp4"); and it creates a video of moving images from left to right. but i want from top to bottom or bottom to top. Thanks in advance

Comment: the ffmpeg overlay docs have an example of a "moving slide" FWIW

Comment: @ShirazAnsari got the solution, or still waiting for it?